# Running an AWS Batch job from an API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am pretty new to AWS so please forgive me if this is a stupid question but seems like I can't find anything regarding this. There's a requirement in one of our applications where we are supposed to run a short action for some of our data stored in db. We have decided to go with AWS Batch to repeat the steps as demanded through our web app.
My question is that is there any straight-forward way to run this job from an action in our Web app say clicking a button and calling an API that runs this batch.

What would be the best course of action to go on about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically work with the AWS Batch service from a C# app, you would need to use this API:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Batch/TBatchClient.html

If you are not familiar with using the AWS SDK for .NET, see

[What is the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)